# VS2015 command line tool msbuild failed for x64 platfrom

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, 64-bit

For a simple VS2015 project(tried also many other simple projects), msbuild failed to build the project for x64 platform.

**Run command as:**

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" C:\tmp\test-VS2015\test-VS2015\test-VS2015.sln /t:build /p:configuration=Debug **/p:platform=x64***

**Error:**

TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe" @C:\Users\gwu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb1afa227772a4a93a9385b9b27b92318.rsp". The operation completed successfully. [C:\tmp\test-VS2015\test-VS2015\test-VS2015\test-VS2015.vcxproj]

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800753/tracker-error-trk0002-failed-to-execute-command-for-building-x64-driver-resources

Comment: Based on your description, I create a simple c++ console demo, and build the project by using your command line, it works, my development environment is: visual studio enterprise 2015 update 3,  Window 10 enterprise. please provide steps or simple demo which I could reproduce your issue on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! My development environment is: visual studio professional 2015, version 1.4.0.25431.01 update 3, Windows 7 Professional.  I created my simple c++ console solution, and sent the solution file to our team of 10 people, to build with the command I gave above, their maching settings were same as mine(except without update 3), some people got the same error as mine, some people built it sucessfully as you did. In this case, what do you think is the besy way for me to solve this issue? -George

Comment: Since some people built it successfully, it seems that some settings cause the issue, please compare the difference settings with the machine which can build and the machine which can't build.

Comment: Do you resolve the issue, if the issue still exist, please feel free let me know.

Comment: The problem ended up being a security software avecto installed on my desktop, killing that process solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is solved. Its an anti-virus software issue on my machine.